# Why do I get a message error when using \tkzDrawLine

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

What is the problem with the `\tkzDrawLine` command from the`tkz-euclide` package. It induces an error message when compiling:

> ! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \tkz
>           @line@start l.36      \tkzDrawLine(C,C'')
>                              The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
>   it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
>   `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
>   undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \tkz
>           @line@end l.36        \tkzDrawLine(C,C'')
>
> > The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
> >     was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I'
> >     and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> >     and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

```
\documentclass[french,tikz,border=2.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}% caractères accentués
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontes extended computer modern (EC)
\usepackage{lmodern} % l'affichage correct des caractères diacritiqués français
\usepackage{babel}% \usepackage[french]{babel} typographie française


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,siunitx}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes ,babel,arrows.meta,angles,calc,shadings,positioning}

\usetkzobj{all}


%\setcounter{page}{4}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(55:8.8){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(55:5.2){B}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](20:3){B'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](20:-3){C'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](180:5){C''}
        \tkzDrawSegment[line cap =round, double distance=3mm](A,C)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,C'')
        \begin{scope}[very thick]
        \tkzDrawVector[-Stealth](B',B)
        \tkzDrawVector(C',C)
        \end{scope}

        \tkzLabelPoint(C){\(C\)}
        \tkzLabelPoint(A){\(A\)}
        \tkzLabelPoint(B){\(B\)}
        \tkzLabelPoint(C''){\(C''\)}
        \tkzDrawLine(C,C'')
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you should use ()'s and not {}'s for some of these? (I'm not bear a computer so I cannot test)

Comment: yes we  use ()'s with tkz-euclide package macros.

Comment: Then start debugging by commenting out all tkz lines, then remove the commenting one line at a time, compiling each time

Comment: the line that is the problem is the last one : \tkzDrawLine(C,C'')

Comment: It appears that `tkz-euclide` is not compatible with the `babel` TikZ library.

Comment: can we add this instruction directly in the package file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the `babel` library. When it's loaded, some TikZ commands are passed through `\scantokens` and so one must ascertain that `@` has the correct category code. Unfortunately, `tkz-euclide` doesn't, in the `\tkzDrawLine` macro (actually in the internal version `\@tkzDrawLine`.

The simplest workaround is to add `\makeatletter` at the appropriate spot.

```
\documentclass[french,tikz,border=2.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}% caractères accentués
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontes extended computer modern (EC)
\usepackage{lmodern} % l'affichage correct des caractères diacritiqués français
\usepackage{babel}% \usepackage[french]{babel} typographie française


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta,angles,calc,shadings,positioning,babel}

\usetkzobj{all}

% make \tkzDrawLine compatible with the babel TikZ library
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tkz@DrawLine}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\makeatletter}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:8.8){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:5.2){B}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](20:3){B'}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](20:-3){C'}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](180:5){C''}
  \tkzDrawSegment[line cap =round, double distance=3mm](A,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,C'')
  \begin{scope}[very thick]
    \tkzDrawVector[-Stealth](B',B)
    \tkzDrawVector(C',C)
  \end{scope}
  \tkzLabelPoint(C){\(C\)}
  \tkzLabelPoint(A){\(A\)}
  \tkzLabelPoint(B){\(B\)}
  \tkzLabelPoint(C''){\(C''\)}
  \tkzDrawLine(C,C'')
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]